# How to collect objects in row using vuetify data iterator?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try to add [Data iterator](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-iterator) to my `Vue` app. When I create a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yQxXOL) example it works properly, but when I use it on my page I have all the items collectes in column, not side by side like in example. Anyone has any ideas what I did wrong?

```
<template>
<div>
  <v-container fluid grid-list-md>
    <v-data-iterator :items="uploadItems" :pagination.sync="pagination" :rows-per-page-items="[4, 8, 12]" :loading="loading" content-tag="v-layout" row wrap>
      <v-flex slot="item" slot-scope="props" lg2>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <h5>{{ props.item.filename }}</h5>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-divider></v-divider>
          <v-list dense>
            <v-list-tile>
              <v-list-tile-content>Status:</v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-content class="align-end">{{ props.item.status }}</v-list-tile-content>
            </v-list-tile>
            <v-list-tile>
              <h4 style="color: red;">{{ props.item.logs.IMPORTER.VERSION.MSG }}</h4>
            </v-list-tile>
            <v-list-tile>
              <h4>VALIDATOR</h4>
            </v-list-tile>
            <v-list-tile v-for="(value, key) in props.item.logs.VALIDATOR">
              <v-list-tile-content>{{ key }}:</v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-content class="align-end">{{ value }}</v-list-tile-content>
            </v-list-tile>
            <v-list-tile>
              <h4>LOGS</h4>
            </v-list-tile>
            <v-list-tile>
              <v-list-tile-content>Chnaged:</v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-content class="align-end">{{ props.item.logs.IMPORTER.CHANGED }}</v-list-tile-content>
            </v-list-tile>
            <v-list-tile>
              <v-list-tile-content>Conflicts:</v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-content class="align-end">{{ props.item.logs.IMPORTER.CONFLICTS }}</v-list-tile-content>
            </v-list-tile>
            <v-list-tile>
              <v-list-tile-content>Correct version:</v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-content class="align-end">{{ props.item.logs.IMPORTER.VERSION.CORRECT_VERSION }}</v-list-tile-content>
            </v-list-tile>
          </v-list>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-data-iterator>
  </v-container>
</div>
</template>
```

I thought it could be older version of `Vue` or `Vuetify`, but I have the same as on CodePen (Vue.js v2.5.17 and Vuetify v1.3.11). I even try to crerate a new `Vue` project and copy example to `App.vue`, but the elements are still in the column, but not in the row.

Comment: Here you have column wrap on the data iterator but row wrap in codepen.

Comment: I forgot to change it back, it doesn't work with row wrap and I just desperately tried everything. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @Alex did you ever get this fixed? I'm having the exact same issue..

Answer (score 1):

Hope it can help, i had the same problem.

```
import Vuetify, { VLayout } from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {   //...   components: { VLayout } })
```

Comment: It works!, I add this code in plugins -> vuetify.js (this answer should be accepted as best answer )

Answer (score 0):

In your Codepen you have the `v-data-iterator` set to row but in your code above it is set to column.

Question code:

```
<v-data-iterator :items="items" :rows-per-page-items="rowsPerPageItems" :pagination.sync="pagination" content-tag="v-layout" hide-actions column wrap>
```

Codepen code:

```
<v-data-iterator :items="items" :rows-per-page-items="rowsPerPageItems" :pagination.sync="pagination" content-tag="v-layout" hide-actions row wrap>
```

Comment: I forgot to change it back, it doesn't work with row wrap and I just desperately tried everything. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: maybe try wrapping the v-container in a v-card instead of a div. Really just continuing in that desperately trying things vein.

Comment: What the difference of wrapping `v-container` in `card` instead of `div`? I have only single container on this page. `Vue` is very intuitive, but it's still black magic for me when I change single parameter and whole page looks different :)

Comment: Nope, still all cards in the column ;(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is necessary, but I managed to get around this by adding the `d-inline-flex` class, as seen below:

```
    <v-data-iterator
      :items="products"
      content-tag="v-layout"
      content-class="d-inline-flex"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this(this is a generic example, adapt this for your problem):

```
<v-data-iterator :items="uploadItems" :rows-per-page-items="4">
  <template v-slot:default="{ items }">
    {{/* Use the items to iterate */}}
    <v-flex v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      {{/* Here render the data of each item */}}
    </v-flex>
  </template>
</v-data-iterator>
```

In your code don't exist the mean to take the **items** in the *slot*.
The *data-iterator* take the data via *items* parameter and expose this via *default* slot.

**Important:** Don't change the **items** name in *template* tag